# 405 Method Not Allowed when creating new item in SharePoint list from remote site

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, spservices

I want to create a simple webpage with a form that can create new items in a SharePoint list. I want to make this as a remote site that just connects to sharepoint.

Since I had a problem with REST API (it returned a 403 Forbidden exception), I decided to use SPServices to do it. When running this script:

```
var itemProperties = [["Title", $("#surname").val()], ["Data", $(".js-my-date").val()]];

$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    batchCmd: "New",
    webURL: 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/me/',
    listName: 'ListNrOne',
    valuepairs: itemProperties,
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        if (xData.status === 200 && xData.statusText === "OK") { 
            $('#result').text("Row created with ID: " + $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_ID") );
        } else {
            $('#result').text("It did not went well");
        }
    }
});
```

...I get 405 Method Not Allowed.

I tried it once inside an aspx file which I kept inside the SharePoint folder structure (it worked).

Now I'm trying from an html file uploaded to a remote site. I get 405 Method Not Allowed.

What is the problem? I have a hunch that it's all about priviliges or credentials, but I have no idea how to deal with it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) errors. This has nothing to do with SPServices, but is a security thing in browsers and servers. The basic idea is that a page coming from some random place shouldn't be able to run script that writes to a different domain. If you think about it, that's a good thing, as it keeps all our interfaces secure. Yet at the same time, it's really annoying when you want to get around it!